# How can i change 4 image post displayed in one row to image slider when the browser is minimized to 480px?

Tags: wordpress, slider, responsive

Following is the code for displaying 4 posts in one row

```
<?php
        $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'article-form',
            'posts_per_page' => 4 // put number of posts that you'd like to display
        ) );
    <?php if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop- >the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col span_1_of_4  " id="recent">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
                    the_post_thumbnail('small-image',array('class' => 'img-responsive')); }?>
            <span class="title-caption"><?php the_title(); ?></span></a>

        </div>

            <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

i want an image slider when the screen is 480px and these 4 image post can be displayed in that slider.

Answer (score 0):

This is more an HTML/JS question than a Wordpress question.

Try doing something like this:

```css
.slider { // Create wrapper for slider
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-item img {
  // Styling for when viewport is smaller than 480px;
 }

@media(min-width: 480px) {
  .slider-item img {
   // Styling for when viewport is bigger than 480px;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  
  // Start loop
  
  <div class="slider-item">
    
    // Load induvidial image here
    
   </div>
  
</div>
```

You can add some JS later to let it all scroll and stuff.